# How to browse each version of each element archived?

Tags: command-line, clearcase

I am looking for a command line either for an algorithm (script) which allows to browse all the versions of each of the elements archived in a VOB UCM or Base Clearcase.

The command find allows to browse each of the elements accessible from an existing view. But It does not thus allow to browse elements uncatalogued.

It is more complicated than the browse of a tree because it is a question of browsing at once the tree of archived elements (files and directory). As well as the tree of branches and versions of every element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ct find -all -nvis -print|gawk "{print \"cleartool lsvtree \"$0}"|cmd
```

(windows syntax, note: some double quotes may be needed around the `$0` is the file has space in it)

That should list all versions (with the `-nvis` option to list elements not visible from the current view).

Since a `find -all` list only one version per element, you have to pass it to a command listing all versions.